# Use Selenium Grid to run performance testing?

Tags: selenium, performance-testing

We use selenium to run functional testing in our project, and continue to move this test stories into selenium grid mode to run performance testing. The concern is that, the scalability issue: how many selenium instance should we deploy? Even one real machine with 10 virtual machine, still not easy to simulate the real traffic.
If not to use selenium grid, how to simulate a real web page, especially with rich ajax ui for your acceptance testing.

Comment: The only part of your question (including the title) that is _not_ subjective is the last sentence. Consider revising.

Comment: thanks, i will make it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with link provided by Kieren ([Grid FAQ](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/faq.html#would_you_recommend_using_selenium_grid_for_performanceload_testing)). **Browsermob** .

> Selenium is not designed for load testing, rather than it is aimed for
>   web application functional/acceptance testing.

But still if you want to use selenium for load testing you should utilize `HTMLUnitDriver` or start with Browser Mob. If you want to achieve parallelism without grid then you can utilize [ISFW](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#testing-frameworks).