# How to perform scalability testing of a web application using selenium

Tags: web-applications, selenium, scalability, load-testing, performance-testing

Do I need some third party tool like load runner for doing a scalability testing of a web application or Can I use selenium to do this for me. Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: I agree with eugene (+1) but do you want to loadtest on your Pentium or do you want to break down Amazon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Load Testing*** - Testing an application under heavy loads,such as testing of a web site under a range of loads to determine at what point the sytem's response time degrades or fails.
**Scalability Testing** - Scalability testing differs from Load Testing in that it focuses on the performance of your Web sites, hardware and software products, and internal applications at all the stages from minimum to maximum load.

Taking into consideration definitions above, we see that scalability testing is a subtype of performance testing. But selenium is not actually designed deliberately for performance testing.
Fundamental idea of selenium is **Selenium automates browsers.**
Some additional info get from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981200/use-selenium-grid-to-run-performance-testing)
Mostly, it is aimed for web application functional/acceptance testing.

Comment: +1 Selenium is aimed to simulate user actions. For load testing OP should check tools like [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)